# Can't create document with doc_type Elasticsearch - Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search 
So im trying to create a document with specific 'doc_type', but when I pass in doc_type argument, I got this error:

**elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'no handler found for uri [/employees/teacher/1] and method [PUT]', 'no handler found for uri [/employees/teacher/1] and method [PUT]')**

Does anyone know what is wrong? 
My code:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    ["localhost"], 
    port=9200, 
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, 
    http_auth=("elastic", "elastic"), 
    use_ssl=True, 
    verify_certs=False
)

body = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': 21
}

# es.indices.create(index = 'employees')

# This line works fine
es.index(index='employees', id = 1, body = body, refresh = 'true' )

# This line caused the error
es.index(index='employees', doc_type='teacher', id = 1, body = body )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping types (aka doc_type) [have been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html) and you should simply use `_doc` instead or not specify the `doc_type` parameter at all like you did in the first `es.index()` statement.

As of release 8.0.0, `doc_type` has even been [removed from the available parameters](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/f659e94fd1eea62b920caef480979f5c08ed3db6/docs/guide/release-notes.asciidoc#removed).